# Java Arrays & Generics : Java Equivalent to C# IEnumerable<T>

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So in C#, I can treat a `string[]` as an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Is there a Java equivalent?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`Iterable<String>` is the equivalent of `IEnumerable<string>`.

It would be an odditity in the type system if arrays implemented `Iterable`. `String[]` is an instance of `Object[]`, but `Iterable<String>` is not an `Iterable<Object>`. Classes and interfaces cannot multiply implement the same generic interface with different generic arguments.

`String[]` will work just like an `Iterable` in the enhanced for loop.

`String[]` can easily be turned into an `Iterable`:

```
Iterable<String> strs = java.util.Arrays.asList(strArray);
```

Prefer collections over arrays (for non-primitives anyway). Arrays of reference types are a bit odd, and are rarely needed since Java 1.5.

Comment: For more info on _why_ you cannot cast between Iterable<String> and Iterable<Object>, check out [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Okay, so now let's address the 500-lb gorilla in the room.  How do you use `Iterable<T>`? -- what is the equivalent `yield return` statement in Java?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I think that's a different question.

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for `Iterable<String>`?

```
Iterable<T> <=> IEnumerable<T>
Iterator<T> <=> IEnumerator<T>
```

Answer (score 5):

`Iterable <T>`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Java equivalent is `Iterable<String>`. Although `String[]` doesn't implement it, you can loop over the elements anyway:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"this", "that"};
for (String s : strings) {
    // do something
}
```

If you really need something that implements `Iterable<String>`, you can do this:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"this", "that"};
Iterable<String> stringIterable = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable<T>` is OK, but there is a small problem. It cannot be used easily in `stream()` i.e lambda expressions.

If you want so, you should get it's spliterator, and use the class `StreamSupport()`.