# How is a for loop structured in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Is it different than C or C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java has one keyword, **for**, but it can be used in two different manner:

```
/* classical, C/C++ school */
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

}
```

for-each style:

```
// more object oriented, since you use implicitly an Iterator 
// without exposing any representation details 
for (String a : anyIterable) {

}
```

it works for any type that implements `Iterable<String>` such as `List<String>`, `Set<String>`, etc.

The latter form works also for **arrays**, [see this question for a more "phisophical approach"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-an-array-is-not-assignable-to-an-iterable).

Answer (score 3):

The following demonstrates the syntax of a java for loop (from [the for loop in Java](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/32.html)):

```
class Hello {
   public static void main (String args[]) {

     System.out.print("Hello ");   // Say Hello
     for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i = i + 1) { // Test and Loop
       System.out.print(args[i]);  
       System.out.print(" ");
     }
     System.out.println();  // Finish the line
   }
}
```

Also see the Wiki entry on [For loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Comment: I'm interested why you did i = i + 1 instead of just i++. Was it just you being verbose or do you have another reason? I've just never seen that used in a very long time.

Comment: @MattC - Didn't write it, just grabbed it from the website referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between java's for-loop syntax and C's is you can declare variables in the initialization field (1st section) of the loop

Comment: IIRC C99 allows declarations like this: for (int i = ... )