# Uses of 'for' in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am fairly new to Java and in another Stack Overflow question about [for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241946/how-is-a-for-loop-structured-in-java) an answer said that there was two uses of for in Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
}


for (String a : anyIterable) {
}
```

I know the first use of for and have used it a lot, but I have never seen the second one. What is it used to do and when would I use it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first of the two you specify is a classic C `for` loop.  This gives the programmer control over the iteration criteria and allows for three operations: the initialization; the loop test ; the increment expression.   Though it is used often to incrementally repeat for a set number of attempts, as in yor example:

```
for (int i=0; i < N : i++)
```

There are many more instances in code where the `for` was use to iterate over collections:

```
for (Iterator iter = myList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
```

To aleviate the boilerplating of the second type (where the third clause was often unused), and to compliment the [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) introduced in Java 1.5, the second of your two examples - the enhanced for loop, or the [`for-each loop`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) - was introduced.

The second is used with arrays and Generic collections.  [See this documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2005/tt0505.html#2).  It allows you to iterate over a generic collection, where you know the type of the `Collection`, without having to cast the result of the `Iterator.next()` to  a known type.

Compare:

```
for(Iterator iter = myList.iterator; iter.hasNext() ; ) {
   String myStr = (String) iter.next();
   //...do something with myStr
}
```

with

```
for (String myStr : myList) {
   //...do something with myStr
 }
```

This 'new style' for loop can be used with arrays as well:

```
String[] strArray= ...
for (String myStr : strArray) {
   //...do something with myStr
}
```

Comment: Or array. Or regular collection if your variable is of type Object :-)

Comment: It is not exclusive to generic collections.

Comment: @pavel - i am willing to make this a wiki answer if you want to add more to it.

Comment: yeah this has nothing to do with generics. it is just the foreach loop that works on all types that implement Iterable (which includes all Collections). the reason that you need to do that cast is because you are not using the generic parameter of Iterator. it should be: "for (Iterator<String> iter = myList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) ... String myStr = iter.next(); ..."

Comment: In your first code block, the colon should be semicolon

Comment: should work for any class that implements interface java.lang.Iterable, in fact. Arrays implement it out of the box. Would work just fine for any of your classes, as long as you implement Iterable

Answer (score 5):

The "for in" loop is mostly eye-candy that makes code easier to read.  (If you pronounce the : as "in").

I use the second type almost exclusively in my own code whenever I'm iterating over a list or array.

I still use the regular for loop when dealing with mostly mathematical code, or when I need an "i" to see how many times I've looped.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a for each loop and basically, it can be used with anything that implements

```
java.lang.Iterable
```

Generic collections implement this interface, but you could make your own class that did as well.  It makes dealing with everything in a list/collection very easy although the downside is that you don't get explicit access to the current number in the list like you do in the traditional loop.  There is some additional overhead associated with this type of loop over traditional loops because of the calls to the iterator classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to iterate through an entire array or Iterable collection.  It basically replaces:

```
for(int i=0; i<N.length; i++)
```

And can be used with Generics which is quite cool

Answer (score 0):

Both  of  them  are   same  in  functionality  ,  but 
**for (String a : anyIterable) {}**  ,  is  more  readable ,less  typing  and  shorter.
**for (int i=0; i < N  : i++)**   index the  collection , by  loop  control variable  **i**  and   **for (String a : anyIterable) {}**    does  not  index  the  collection