# How to execute 1 command x times in java

Tags: java, loops

I'd like to ask how to execute 1 command multiple times

for example this code

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

I want to run it 500 times
how do i do it ?

Thank You

Regards
Wilhelmus

Comment: This is not a coding service Please try your self something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uses of 'for' in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242766/uses-of-for-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

---

Please go through a basic Java tutorial.
One can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

Answer (score 44):

With Java 8 Streams you could do it like that

```
IntStream.range(0, 500).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));
```

Comment: @kiedysktos No, since the second parameter of range() is exclusive... . rangeClosed() on the other hand is inclusive.

Comment: yes indeed you're right

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
              System.out.println("Hello world");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
     //the code you would like to loop here
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     for(int j=0; j<500; j++){
          System.out.println("Hello world");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x=0;x<500;x++){
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

You should read about control structures. They are the basic building blocks of programming.

Answer (score 0):

New in Java 11:

```
 String word = "Hi";
 System.out.println(word.repeat(5));
 
 // Output: HiHiHiHiHi
```