# How do I turn my “for” loop into a “for of” loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

i am trying to turn this for loop into for each loop.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {
            if (appointments.get(i).equals(appointment)) { 
              appointments.get(i).setAvailability(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uses of 'for' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242766/uses-of-for-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`for-each` `appt` in `appointments`. Like,

```
for (Appointment appt : appointments) {
    if (appt.equals(appointment)) {
        appt.setAvailability(true);
    }
}
```

Or, if using Java 8+ you could `stream` the `appointments`. Like,

```
appointments.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.equals(appointment))
        .forEach(appt -> appt.setAvailability(true));
```