# In Java what do arrays inherit from? Can I do this?

Tags: c#, java, arrays

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm used to C# so my Java framework knowledge is not so good.

I have a couple of arrays:

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
String[] names = new String[10];

//populate the arrays
```

Now I want to make a generic function which will print out the values in these arrays, something like the following (this should work in C#)

```
private void PrintAll(IEnumerable items)
{    
    foreach(object item in items)       
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

All I would have to do now is to

```
PrintAll(names);
PrintAll(numbers);
```

How can I do this in Java? What is the inheritance tree for the array in Java?

Many thanks

Bones

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-an-array-is-not-assignable-to-an-iterable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays only implement `Serializable` and `Cloneable` in Java<sup>1</sup>; so there is no generic way to do this. You'd have to implement a separate method for each type of array (since primitive arrays like `int[]` cannot be cast to `Object[]`).

But in this case, you don't have to because [`Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) can do it for you:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

This will yield something like:

```
[Tom, Dick, Harry]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If that's not good enough, you're stuck having to implement a version of your method for each possible array type, like `Arrays` does.

```
public static void printAll(Object[] items) {
    for (Object o : items)
        System.out.println(o);
}
public static void printAll(int[] items) {
    for (int i : items)
        System.out.println(i);
}
public static void printAll(double[] items) {
    for (double d : items)
        System.out.println(d);
}
// ...
```

Note that the above only applies to arrays. [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) implements [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), so you can use:

```
public static <T> void printAll(Iterable<T> items) {
    for (T t : items)
        System.out.println(t);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> See [JLS §10.7 Array Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7).

Comment: Thought of the same, but it includes the array string representation; e.g. "[1, 2]". I don't know if that's OK or not.

Comment: There just aren't that many native types, so adding the individual methods shouldn't be that big a burden.

Comment: There are eight primitives plus Object, so that could get tedious if you're doing more than one method with each.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers state, `int[]` and `String[]` have no common superclass that will let you do it. One thing you can do is wrap the arrays in a list before passing them to your `PrintAll()` function. This is easily done using `Arrays.asList(myArray)`. Then your `PrintAll()` function can take in a `Collection` or `Iterable` and iterate it that way.

Comment: Or better yet, an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

(It won't work for type int as it is a primitive type. You could use the object `Integer` instead.)

```
public void print(Object[] objects){
    for (Object o: objects){
        System.out.println(o);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to find which is the superclass of an array (which is a *normal* Object)

```
    String[] array = {"just", "a", "test"};

    Object obj = array;  // not really needed, just as example
    System.out.println("class: " + obj.getClass());
    System.out.println("super: " + obj.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

not the solution but answer to the question (title at least).
(*I would suggest Arrays.toString as already done by mmyers*)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as to what class- have [a look at the docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). java.lang.Object is the answer.

<s>In terms of things you should know about for iteration- Have a look at the Java [enhanced for each statement](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html), and [Interface Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) 
`Iterable<E>`.</s> As others have commented, unfortunately Array does not implement `Iterable<E>`.

Comment: Sadly, arrays don't implement `Iterable`.

Comment: No they don't, but enhanced for each works with arrays and Iterable<E>.