# Why doesn't "array instanceof Iterable" compile in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

```
Object[] array = new Object[]{};
System.out.println((array instanceof Serializable));//passed
System.out.println((array instanceof Cloneable));//passed
```

This code compiles and runs.  The output is:

```
true
true
```

However, this code doesn't compile:

```
System.out.println((array instanceof Iterable));//not passed
```

The Eclipse compiler reports:

> Incompatible conditional operand types Object[] and Iterable

I found that arrays can only be compared between interface`Serializable` and `Cloneable` when using operation `instanceof`.  Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Related: [Why is an array not assignable to iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [JLS, Java SE 7 edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), §[15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) (Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`):

> If a cast of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be rejected as a
>   compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces
>   a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression
>   could never be true.

And §[15.16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) (Cast Expressions) states:

> It is a compile-time error if the compile-time type of the operand may never be
>   cast to the type specified by the cast operator according to the rules of casting
>   conversion (§[5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)).

Finally, §[5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) (Reference Type Casting) states:

> Given a compile-time reference type *S* (source) and a compile-time reference type
>   *T* (target), a casting conversion exists from *S* to *T* if no compile-time errors occur
>   due to the following rules.
>
> *[...]*
>
> If *S* is an array type *SC*[], that is, an array of components of type *SC*:
>
> - If *T* is an interface type, then a compile-time error occurs unless *T* is the type
>     `java.io.Serializable` or the type `Cloneable` (the only interfaces implemented
>     by arrays).

Therefore, Java *requires* that your test to see if an array type is an instance of `java.lang.Iterable` results in a compile-time error.

If you want to try and make it work (always return `false`) anyway, you can cast the array to `Object` first, like so:

```
System.out.println((((Object)array) instanceof Iterable));
```

Comment: You could cast to object, but you'd simply end up with "false" every time, as array classes don't implement Iterable.  There is special support for arrays in the enhanced for statement, just like there is for iterable.  Since array types are not assignment compatible to an Iterable, you get a compile error, much like if you tried to cast a String to a Number.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing suitability of an object for use in a foreach loop, and the `Iterable` interface, which arrays do not implement.

Both arrays and Iterable are supported with the foreach syntax.

That doesn't mean that arrays are Iterable.

Comment: @GregKopff It's the question asked in the title.

Comment: No, the question is not why an array is not iterable; it is why that line is not considered valid Java by the compiler.

Comment: Does it have some limits on the relation between left-operand and right-operand when using operation 'instanceof' , I have found that '"123" instanof Iterable' would not passed and if I cast "123" to an Object reference , it will be passed!

Comment: It's a question of whether the object can possibly match that interface now or in the future. "123" is effectively a final value so it can never be Iterable where an Object could be in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because both `Serializable` and `Cloneable` are marker interfaces where as `Iterable` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Because java is a static language, so the compiler knows an array won't be `Iterable` at compile time, the compiler knows that `array instanceof Iterable` could never be true, so it trigger a compile-time error to warn you.

Comment: I think it may be like this , the IDE is really intelligent!

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai: or maybe the Java compiler is "really intelligent".