# letting a java function accept a collection or an array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, function-declaration

I am trying to write a function that takes some strings and does something with them.

The only thing I'm going to do that the set of strings is loop over them. Right now I end up with an awkward construct along the lines of

```
public void foo(String[] myStrings){
    foo(java.util.Arrays.asList(myStrings));
}

public void foo(Iterable<String> myStrings){
    for(String i : myStrings){
        bar(i);
    }
}
```

which feels redundant since

```
for(String i : myStrings){
    bar(i);
}
```

would be perfectly valid code for myStrings of type String[].

Is there a class that I can have foo accept which will allow both collections and arrays?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Why is an array not assignable to Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)

Short answer: no. Array types are synthetic code, as I understand it, and thus do not implement `Iterable` or any other types. You need to provide an overloaded method or require clients to call `Arrays.asList` at the call site.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was still trying to convince java that deep in its heart it was python.

Comment: Haha, no duck typing here -- sorry. :)

Comment: Welcome to the world of verbose typing. Java's based on the principle of WET rather than DRY (as in Write Everything Twice rather than Dont Repeat Yourself).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately array does not implement `Iterable`, despite the for-each loop working on both.

You could exclusively only accept `Iterable`, as passing around arrays is a bit old school (the performance benefits of arrays over `ArrayList` is negligible). An existing array can be easily wrapped and converting to a `List` using [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Comment: That is a good call. I use ArrayLists in any new code that I write, but there are a lot of arrays floating around that I've inherited.

Answer (score 3):

Although arrays can be used in a for-each loop, they do not implement `Iterable`. There are simply two possibilities, either overload the method as you've stated, or just provide only the iterable variant and force the client to call `Arrays.asList()`.

In case you want to also provide the array overload, you might change its signature from simple array to varargs:

```
public void foo(String... myStrings){
    foo(java.util.Arrays.asList(myStrings));
}
```

In such case, beware of the incompatibility between primitive arrays and primitive-wrapper arrays:

```
static void foo(int... ints) {}
foo(new Integer[] {1, 2}); // compile error
```

and:

```
static void foo(Integer... integers) {}
foo(new int[] { 1, 2 }); // compile error
```

**And the most obscure part, with generic varargs:**

```
static <T> T[] foo(T... ts) {
    return ts;
}
```

If you pass an array of Integers:

```
Integer[] integers = { 1, 2 };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(foo(integers)));
> [1, 2]
```

The value of `ts` is an array of Integers with 2 elements: `1` and `2`.

However, if you pass an array of primitive ints, a funny thing happens:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2 };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(foo(ints)));
> [[1, 2]]
```

In this case, the value of ts is an array of int arrays (`int[][]`) with only one element, which is the originally passed array. The reason for this is that an `int` isn't an `Object` (autoboxing doesn't help here), while an array of ints is, so the value of the `T` type parameter becomes `int[]`.