# Can I iterate over an array defined within a for-loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Does Java offer a way to do something like the following without resorting to declaring the array in a separate variable?

```
for (String s : {"HEY", "THERE"}) {
    // ...
}
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
for (String s : new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("HEY"); add("THERE"); }}) {
    // ...
}
```

which isn't pretty.

Comment: Don't think the second is also correct, u will be iterating over a memory address not actual String[].,

Comment: @SathishJayapal No, the second does work.

Comment: interesting, it did. Lesson for the day, cheers.http://ideone.com/jnkExT

Comment: Yeah, I think it's pretty hard to accidentally access the memory location of an object in Java. C, on the other hand...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the least you can do is this:

```
for (String s : new String[]{"HEY", "THERE"}) {
    // ...
}
```

Since `Array`s are "iterable" in Java (although [not implementing `Iterable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)), you could iterate over an `Array` instead of an `ArrayList`, which could also be in-line initialized.

Comment: Nitpick: arrays don't implement the `Iterable` interface. Something different is going on when using enhanced for on them.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (String s : Arrays.asList("HEY", "THERE")) {
    // ...
}
```

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but there you have it.

Comment: Mostly just curiosity but I learned three things from this question: `Arrays.asList`, `new Object[]{}`, and curiosity has no "u" in it.