# How can I find an element whether it exists in a List or not using Google Guava?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have a `List<String>` I need to find whether the particular string exists inside a List or not.

for Eg:

`String str = "apple";`

`List<String> listObject = Lists.newArrayList("apple", "orange", "banana");`

I need to find whether `str` exists in `listObject` or not using Google Guava.

So I need a `true` or `false` result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want `Guava` for this?

Comment: Guava is the new jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm agree that this can be done (and should, maybe) with the standard Collections API, but anyway, in Guava you can do it like this:

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"one", "two", "3", "4"});
boolean exists = FluentIterable.from(strList).contains("two");
```

Comment: You could even replace `.contains("two")` by `.anyMatch(Predicates.equalTo("two"))` for a bit more obfuscation.

Comment: The main difference between this solution and the Collections API is that this solution works on any `Iterable`. In other words, the `Arrays.asList()` part is redundant. Just pass the array straight in.

Comment: @Stewart: Arrays are not `Iterable`, unfortunately. Plus, you can write `Arrays.asList(array).contains("two")` if all you need is the contains check.

Comment: Dah! Shorthand `for` loop strikes again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable

Answer (score 18):

This is a standard part of the Java Collections API:

```
boolean exists = listObject.contains(str);
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't think you did.

Comment: The question was specifically asking how to do it using Guava, and I missed that point. `FluentIterable.contains()` calls `Iterables.contains()` which logic is different, including suppressing `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that there is no good reason to want to do this _using Guava_ when the way one _should_ do this (as you pointed out) exists in the standard APIs. And the behavior of throwing `NPE` from `Collection.contains(null)` is rare enough (I'm not sure I know of any implementations that actually do that) that no one should be using `FluentIterable.contains` _just_ for that unless they know it's something they need to worry about. And `ArrayList` doesn't do that anyway.