# Why can't Lists be included in `Integer...` parameter

Tags: java, arrays, list, methods, parameters

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
public void add(Integer... newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why, but I can't put an `ArrayList<Integer>` into the method.

I am more than happy to just copy the method for Lists but I thought that there had to be a more efficient way.

I tried the following thinking that I could do what you can do for a catch block:

```
public void add(Integer... | List<Integer> newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}
```

However, after a quick StackOverfow, found it was impossible. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can convert your list before you call your method there are many ways to do that

Comment: Or convert the varargs to a list with [`List.of(E...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and then call the `add(List<Integer>)` implementation.

Comment: integerList.add(otherIntegerList.toArray(new Integer[]{})); Maybe not efficient or pretty but it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method accepting `Integer...` cannot consume a collection. it can only consume an array of Integer's.

The best you can do is use method overloading.

```
public void add(Integer...newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}

public void add(List<Integer> newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd stick with the above but if you want to avoid code duplication and instead construct *a new list every time* the `public void add(Integer...newIntegers) {...}` is called then you can do as @Sweeper has suggested in the comments.

```
public void add(Integer... newIntegers) {
     add(Arrays.asList(newIntegers));
}

public void add(List<Integer> newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to avoid repetition. Quote: "I am more than happy to just copy the method for Lists but I thought that there had to be a more efficient way."

Comment: @Sweeper is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank's for that. Bang on.

Comment: I was thinking that OP could create an `add(List<Integer>)` and have the `add(Integer...)` overload call that by converting the integer array to a list. Imagine if the method were way longer than this.

Comment: Really? I'm surprised that it's not a feature since both ways return an Iterable instance.

Comment: `Iterable` is an interface in Java. Anything that implements `Iterable` can be put in an enhanced `for` loop, but just because an array can be put into an enhanced `for` loop as well, doesn't make it `Iterable`. They are two different things: one is an array, the other isn't.

Comment: Oh well. Accepted then.

Comment: @Sweeper well you could do that to avoid _code duplication_ but now you're constructing a new list with all the elements from the array. surely that is not more efficient than what's shown above. Anyway,  I will provide a solution for that and let the OP decide what they want.

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable

Comment: @Aominè Arrays.asList is pretty efficient; it doesn't clone the array or copy its contents. Of course there is a small cost to creating any object.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda while your edit is certainly true it's more efficient to do it the way I have shown. See the comment Andy Turner has left under the other answer _creating a list from an array is an o(1) operation; creating an array from a list is o(size)._. hence I've recommended proceeding with the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload it by doing the below code, it will let you reuse the Add method previously created.

```
public void add(Integer...newIntegers) {
    for (Integer i : newIntegers) {
        integers.add(i);
    }
}

public void add(List<Integer> newIntegers) {
   add(newIntegers.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new));
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way round: creating a list from an array is an o(1) operation; creating an array from a list is o(size).