# Java method arguments not applicable

Tags: java, collections

First, appologies for the lack of a better title. Hopefully someone with more experience in Java is able to change it to something more appropiate.

So I'm faced with the following exception:

> The method copyPartialMatches(String, Iterable, T) in the type
>   StringUtil is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[],
>   List)

The [documentation](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/util/StringUtil.html) for this method states:

> Parameters:
>       token - String to search for
>       originals - An iterable collection of strings to filter.
>       collection - The collection to add matches to

My code:

```
public class TabHandler implements TabCompleter {
    private static final String[] params = {"help", "menu", "once", "repeat", "infinite", "cancel"};

    @Override
    public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        final List<String> completions = new ArrayList<>();
        StringUtil.copyPartialMatches(args[0], params, completions);

        Collections.sort(completions);
        return completions;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain the problem lies with the `completions` List. Perhaps this is not a valid collection? It was my understanding that it was, but right now I'm just at a loss here. So hopefully you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in an actual `List` as the second parameter to `StringUtil#copyPartialMatches`:

```
@Override
public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
    final List<String> completions = new ArrayList<>();
    StringUtil.copyPartialMatches(args[0], Arrays.asList(params), completions);
    //                                     ^^^ change is here

    Collections.sort(completions);
    return completions;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue straight away ^^ Will accept when able to :)

Answer (score 1):

`String[]` isn't `Iterable`. Change

```
StringUtil.copyPartialMatches(args[0], params, completions);
```

to pass a `List<String>` instead. Something like,

```
StringUtil.copyPartialMatches(args[0], Arrays.asList(params), completions);
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solved the issue. I will accept Tim Biegeleisen's answer because he was slightly faster. But both your answers are equaly as good :)

Comment: @icecub No problem. Glad the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[Why is an array not assignable to Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)

`Arrays` don't implement the Iterable interface. That's why the method signature isn't matching. Converting the `array` to a `list` works since the latter implements the interface.

The `forEach` loop for arrays is a special case (arrays don't implement the `Iterable<T>` interface yet the work with the `forEach` loop).

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this information will be usefull to future readers