# Generic method with type which extends Iterable doesn't work

Tags: java, generics

Assignment: Write a generic static method `print()` that prints the elements of any object that implements the `Iterable<E>` interface.

```
public class ThisUtil
{
    public static <T extends Iterable<T>> void print(T[] anArray) {


        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(T element: anArray)
        {
            stringList.add(element.toString());
        }
        String result = String.join(",", stringList);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] list = {1, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7};
        ThisUtil.print(list);
    }
}
```

I got error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Integer conforms to
>   Iterable.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you advance.

Comment: simply change your method to `public static <T> void print(T[] anArray)`

Comment: `T extends Iterable<T>` doesn't make any sens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
public static <T extends Iterable<T>> void print(T[] anArray)
```

you say that you will pass array of elements which type extends `Iterable` but you simply want to iterate over this array. In your case you can change your method signature to :

```
public static <T> void print(T[] anArray)
```

because arrays can be used in `for-each` out of the box.

**EDIT :**

You are probably looking for something like this :

```
public static <E, I extends Iterable<E>> void print(I iterable) {

    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(E element: iterable) {
        stringList.add(element.toString());
    }
    String result = String.join(",", stringList);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

but then you cannot use it with arrays since [arrays are not Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable) but the can be used in `for-each`.

Comment: Thank you very much, michalk. But the requirement was using <T extends Iterable<T>> for any type collections.

Comment: So you want to pass array of collections for example? I do not really understand your requirement. And also arrays are not collections...

Comment: Assignment: Write a generic static method print() that prints the elements of any object that implements the Iterable<E> interface.

Comment: Your first suggestion can be written as `public static void print(Object[] anArray)` and your second suggestion can be written as `public static void print(Iterable<?> iterable)`