# Why do for-each loops work for arrays? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, iterable

I don't understand how a for each loop can iterate through an Array in Java. My understanding is that for each loops can iterate though any class that implements the Iterable interface, but Arrays in Java don't implement Iterable, so how is it possible a for each loop can be used on them?

Answer (score 4):

If the right-hand side of the `for (:)` idiom is an `array` rather than an `Iterable` object, the internal code uses an `int` index counter and checks against `array.length` instead. That's why it can be used to loop through arrays. See the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for further details.

Part of this answer was exempted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work). You can take a look at that question too.

I would like to add, if you want you can easily convert java `array` to `Iterable`:

```
Integer arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
// or
Iterable<Integer> iterable = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: Is there any source that describes WHY they decided the way they did? In particular why they decided that Array will not implement Iterable? I can think about some reasons, but I am curious …

Comment: You just copied & pasted someone's answer as your own. Instead, mark as duplicate. You didn't even try to reword it.. -1

Comment: Thanks for your words @VinceEmigh. I didn't mark it as duplicate because the questions are different. I just took the part which would make sense for him. Also, I've mentioned the actual link. I don't think I've done anything against community policy. #Peace

Comment: @tquadrat Hera are some great answers that might enlighten you a bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable

Comment: Do you know if there are any data structures outside of array that can be used in for each loop without iterable implemented?

Comment: Not anything that I can think of at the moment. Thing is, most of the well-known data structures in Java (except `Map`) extends the `Collection` interface, and the `Collection` interface extends the `Iterable` interface. So, there's not much option for a data structure outside of an array to be used in `for-each` loop.

Answer (score 2):

As per [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> EnhancedForStatement: for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType
> VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement
>
> EnhancedForStatementNoShortIf: for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType
> VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) StatementNoShortIf

Java foreach loop or enhanced for statement is translated into a basic for statement, as follows:

1. If the type of `Expression` is a subtype of `Iterable<X>` for some type argument X, then let `I` be the type `java.util.Iterator<X>;` otherwise, let `I` be the raw type `java.util.Iterator.`

The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

2. Otherwise, the `Expression` necessarily has an array type, `T[]`.

The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```