# Java How can I have a method return either a child or parent class object

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have two classes where one class inherits the other one as given below:

```
public class UserData {
    protected final String emailAddress;
    protected final String name;

    public UserData(final String emailAddress, final String name) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Optional<String> getEmailAddress() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.emailAddress);
    }

    public Optional<String> getName() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.name);
    }
}
```

```
public class EmployeeData extends UserData {
    protected final String designation;

    public EmployeeData(
            final String emailAddress,
            final String name,
            final String designation
    ) {
        super(emailAddress, name);
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public Optional<String> getDesignation() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.designation);
    }

}
```

I need to create method in another class that can return either one of these objects and have all getters accessible. I already tried making the return type `UserData` for both kinds of objects (example given below) but that way, I cannot access the `getDesignation` getter for EmployeeData.  Is there a better way inheritance can be setup to avoid this problem where I cannot access child-specific properties?

```
public UserData getData() {
    if (...some condition) {
        return new EmployeeData("address@provider.com", "myName", "Dev")
    }
    else {
        return new UserData("address@provider.com", "myName");
    }
}
```

I did look into these stackoverflow questions but couldn't quite figure it out for my use case

- [C# how to make a function that can return either child or parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559355/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-function-that-can-return-either-child-or-parent-class)
- [What's the equivalent of C# IEnumerable in Java? The covariant-capable one, not the Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664729/whats-the-equivalent-of-c-sharp-ienumerable-in-java-the-covariant-capable-one)

Comment: Without providing a "speciality" method for each return type, the only way you could do is to cast the returned result (making use of `instanceof`)

Comment: No, this is pretty much the way it works.  Why do you assume that the `UserData` you get back is necessarily something that has a `getDesignation()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the object we are returning is of type `UserData`, we will be unable to call methods that are added within the child class, `EmployeeData`. You could create the `getDesignation()` method inside the `UserData` class and have it return an empty optional object.

```
public Optional<String> getDesignation() {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

In this case, you can now override the method within the `EmployeeData` class to return `designation` as an `Optional` like this,

```
@Override
public Optional<String> getDesignation() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.designation);
}
```

Now you will have access to the `getDestination()` method from returned object of `getData()`, but you will have to be careful and understand that if the returned type is of `UserData`, then when calling `getDesignation()` you will be receiving an `Optional.empty()` object.