# How to convert an int array to String with toString method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I am using trying to use the `toString(int[])` method, but I think I am doing it wrong:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)

My code:

```
int[] array = new int[lnr.getLineNumber() + 1];
int i = 0;

System.out.println(array.toString());
```

The output is:

```
[I@23fc4bec
```

Also I tried printing like this, but:

```
System.out.println(new String().toString(array));  // **error on next line**
The method toString() in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

**I took this code out of bigger and more complex code, but I can add it if needed. But this should give general information.**

I am looking for output, like in Oracle's documentation:

> The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).

Answer (score 323, accepted):

What you want is the `Arrays.toString(int[])` method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int[] array = new int[lnr.getLineNumber() + 1];
int i = 0;

..      

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

There is a static `Arrays.toString` helper method for every different primitive java type; the one for [`int[]` says this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)):

> ```
> public static String toString(int[] a)
> ```
>
> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets (`"[]"`). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters `", "` (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(int)`. Returns `"null"` if `a` is null.

Comment: What's the easiest way to go from "[x, y, z]" back to an array or List?

Comment: @nerdistcolony There's nothing as clean as Arrays.toString to go the other way - but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456367/reverse-parse-the-output-of-arrays-tostringint for some suggestions.

Comment: @Sbodd - I came up with an example based on an ArrayList and posted the answer. It was specific to a problem I needed to solve for an app I'm porting, but might save someone some time.

Answer (score 40):

```
System.out.println(array.toString());
```

should be:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 39):

Very much agreed with @Patrik M, but the thing with Arrays.toString is that it includes **"["** and **"]"** and **","** in the output. So I'll simply use a regex to remove them from outout like this

```
String strOfInts = Arrays.toString(intArray).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", "");
```

and now you have a String which can be parsed back to `java.lang.Number`, for example,

```
long veryLongNumber = Long.parseLong(intStr);
```

Or you can use the java 8 streams, if you hate regex,

```
String strOfInts = Arrays
            .stream(intArray)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .reduce((a, b) -> a.concat(",").concat(b))
            .get();
```

Comment: The regex one is really nasty ...

Answer (score 24):

You can use [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
String res = Arrays.toString(array);
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: how to retrieve int[] array from this Output.

Answer (score 17):

The toString method on an array only prints out the memory address, which you are getting.
You have to loop though the array and print out each item by itself

```
for(int i : array) {
 System.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the utility I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900869/how-do-i-write-a-method-which-would-work-on-both-lists-and-arrays/10901267#10901267), you can have a more control over the string representation you get for your array.

```
String[] s = { "hello", "world" };
RichIterable<String> r = RichIterable.from(s);
r.mkString();                 // gives "hello, world"
r.mkString(" | ");            // gives "hello | world"
r.mkString("< ", ", ", " >"); // gives "< hello, world >"
```

Answer (score 3):

This function returns a array of int in the string form like "6097321041141011026"

```
private String IntArrayToString(byte[] array) {
        String strRet="";
        for(int i : array) {
            strRet+=Integer.toString(i);
        }
        return strRet;
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use StringBuilder rather than direct string concatenation - for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of going from a list of strings, to a single string, back to a list of strings.

Compiling:

```
$ javac test.java
$ java test
```

Running:

```
    Initial list:

        "abc"
        "def"
        "ghi"
        "jkl"
        "mno"

    As single string:

        "[abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno]"

    Reconstituted list:

        "abc"
        "def"
        "ghi"
        "jkl"
        "mno"
```

Source code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfStrings= new ArrayList<>();
        listOfStrings.add("abc");
        listOfStrings.add("def");
        listOfStrings.add("ghi");
        listOfStrings.add("jkl");
        listOfStrings.add("mno");

        show("\nInitial list:", listOfStrings);

        String singleString = listOfStrings.toString();

        show("As single string:", singleString);

        List<String> reconstitutedList = Arrays.asList(
             singleString.substring(0, singleString.length() - 1)
                  .substring(1).split("[\\s,]+"));

        show("Reconstituted list:", reconstitutedList);
    }

    public static void show(String title, Object operand) {
        System.out.println(title + "\n");
        if (operand instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("    \"" + operand + "\"");
        } else {
            for (String string : (List<String>)operand)
                System.out.println("    \"" + string + "\"");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody asked for this.

Comment: @Roberto It uses related technology (Array methods), and I provided it to supplement the int related answer for people working with array conversions even though it show strings because I knew there were already int related solutions.. No reason to downvote it and being smug about it.  Maybe try doing some good around here before trying to trash other people.

Comment: No you're wrong. First sentence clarifies the purpose, and it is related enough. Contribute something useful before thinking about crapping on other users. You've done nothing other than make things worse for others.