# Java - Calling a method that returns a string of ints from an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, methods

I am working with a program in which I need to use a method call to return a String from an int array.  This is what I have of the method so far (I am required to use a method with this header and parameters)

```
    public String toString()
{
for (int i=0;i<NUM_POCKETS;i++)
    {
    this.getPocketCount(i);
    }
}
```

I basically need the loop to go through all of my "pockets" (array items) and return the stored values into a String to be returned.

I could be missing something very obvious, but for the life of me I do not understand how this information would be stored and returned to the Driver as a String.  I know the loop logic is there, but how do I store each increment of i into a String as the loop progresses?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's more than concatenation, there's also the formatting of an int to a string.

Comment: Looking for something like this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/java-how-to-convert-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method) ??

Comment: Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[, \\[\\]]","")

Answer (score 3):

"`I am working with a program in which I need to use a method call to return a String from an int array.`"

If this isn't a homework problem, you can simply use `Arrays.toString(int[] array)`.

```
String myString = Arrays.toString(myIntArray);
```

Otherwise, maybe you can do something like this:

```
String getStringFromIntArray(int[] array) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int num : array)
    builder.append(num)
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: This would be the "Java" way to do it. OP may be looking for the "learn about general programming" way.

Comment: Well, he didn't say it was homework or anything, so i assume he's allowed to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the StringBuilder class.  The specification for Java 6 is here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

You would need a StringBuilder object and just append the value to the object using the .append() function.

Comment: This would indeed be one of the most elegant solutions, next to `Arrays.toString(...)`. Especially if you want to add further information, this should be the solution of choice.

Answer (score 1):

as long as `this.getPocketCount(i);` gives you the value of the array on position i:

```
public String toString() {
    String returnstring= "";    //init empty string
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POCKETS; i++) {
        returnstring += this.getPocketCount(i)+" "; //append(concat) to string
    }
    returnstring = returnstring.substring(0, returnstring.length()-1);  //remove the last " "
    return returnstring;    //return string
}
```

the `+` sign appends the next string 
`"Hello"+" "+"World"` becomes `"Hello World"`

Edit:

```
public String toString() {
    String returnstring= "";    //init empty string
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POCKETS-1; i++) { //-1 to place last later
        returnstring += this.getPocketCount(i)+" "; //append to string
    }
    returnstring += this.getPocketCount(NUM_POCKETS-1)  //append the last value
    return returnstring;    //return string
}
```

Comment: If no outside tools are to be used, this would be a good solution. Maybe only add the space if you're not looking at the last element or something.

Comment: this would cause many if statments... i will fix it in a better way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you specifically want to build your String from within the loop, you could use a `StringBuilder`. It is more verbose than the one-liner offered by `Arrays.toString()`, but you asked for it:

e.g.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(NUM_POCKETS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POCKETS; i++) {
        sb.append(this.getPocketCount(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Using a `StringBuilder` within a loop is faster than performing concatenation of each individual element. See: [when to use StringBuilder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)