# How to use getBytes() in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cryptography, encode

## How to Use GetBytes() Method in VC++

#### In Java  ,

```
         **byte[] saltedPassword = (password + getSalt()).getBytes();**
```

#### output :

```
 SaltedPassword :[B@3eca90
```

here saltedPassword get **encoded value**  in the **same way i want to implement in VC++**

Please anyone give me a Solution.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: If you want help, post what you tried and ask a question. We don't do "solutions", that's a job and for a job, I'd want to be paid.

Comment: "\[B@3eca90" looks like the result of an `Object.toString()` call; it's not an encoded value. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/java-how-to-convert-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method). You probably want to hex or Base64 encode the byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using MFC goes like this:

```
CString getSalt()
{
  return (CString)"mysalt" ;  // dummy function, should be replaced by *your* code
}
...

CByteArray saltedPassword ;
CString password ;
...

CString saltedpasswordstring = password + getSalt() ;

for (int i = 0; i < saltedpasswordstring.GetLength() ; i++)
{
  saltedPassword.Add((BYTE)saltedpasswordstring[i]) ;
}

// now the saltedPassword array contains what you want
```

But maybe you should learn MFC and/or C++ before