# How to pass an array from servlet to jsp page?

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

I have achieved sending an integer variable to a jsp page using the following code:

```
resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibNum=" + fibNum));
```

But when I try the same to pass the array, `int[] fibSequence` I get the following passed to the address bar of the jsp page:

[image: fibSequence]

Does anyone have any advice on how I can output the array value passed over to the jsp page?`

This is how I sent the array across to the result jsp page within the doPost():

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        // read form fields
        String fibNum = req.getParameter("fibNum");


        try{
              //Get reference from server's registry
              Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1");

              //Lookup server object from server's registry
              IFibonacci fibonacci_proxy = (IFibonacci)registry.lookup("PowerObject");


              int fibMax = Integer.parseInt(fibNum);

             //Invoke server object's methods 
             //Get Fibonacci array.
             int[] fibSequence = fibonacci_proxy.fibonacciArrayTest(fibMax);


             for (int value : fibSequence) {
                System.out.println(value);
             }


            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibSequence));


            }catch(NotBoundException nbe){
              nbe.printStackTrace();
            }catch(RemoteException re){
              re.printStackTrace();
            }

            //send input to the result page using a redirect
            //resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibNum=" + fibNum));
            resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibSequence=" + fibSequence));

          }
```

How I've tried to retrieve the array values on the jsp page and print them, but I'm getting a `fibSequence cannot be resolved to a variable` although this is the name of the array passed over:

```
<a href="home.jsp">Return to Main</a><br>
             <%String[] var_array=request.getParameterValues("fibSequence");%>
             <%System.out.print(""+fibSequence);%>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where is `fibSeq` defined? Is it in scope?

Comment: It's a **very bad idea** to pass arguments to be displayed in the next view as part of the query string. I recommend you using forwarding instead.

Comment: `fibSequence` or `fibSeq`?

Comment: Oh I see the mistake now, should be fibSequence, `fibSeq` is the variable name I've used in the jsp page.

Comment: You should also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/java-how-to-convert-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust the compiler. fiBSeq ist not defined. You defined fibSequence. But passing that array as an argument will not work, because you will pass (int[]).toString() which is probably not what you want. You can serialize and encode it, if it is not too big. Or post it.

EDIT 1

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
System.out.print(""+array);//<-- print [I@15db9742  or similar
```

EDIT 2

Encoding the array on the sender side

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
String param = Arrays.toString(array);
param = param.substring(1, param.length()-1);//removing enclosing []
String encArray = URLEncoder.encode(param, "utf-8");
    
// Send encArray as parameter.
resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibSequence=" + encArray));
```

Decoding the array on the receiver side

```
String encArray = request.getParameterValues("fibSequence");
String decArray = URLDecoder.decode(encArray,"utf-8");
//Now you can parse the list into an Integer list
String [] var_array = decArray.split(",");
```

In jsp, put the code between **<% ... %>**. If you get some *unresolved symbol* errors you have to import the missing libraries.
Can be one or more of the following, simply copy the statements at the top of the page.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
```

(maybe java.util is imported per default, I am not sure)

> **BUT ATTENTION**
>
> Be aware of not sending too much data in this manner! The size of an URL maybe is not unlimited. Also the data is visible in the URL, a 'nasty' user could simply copy and reproduce requests.
> A better way to send data is using HTTP post.

Comment: Please see edits to my question, the array is passed over but I'm not sure how to output it to the jsp page.I know in a java class you can just use a println or toString, but how can I print it within this type of page?

Comment: Simply with `out.print(...)`. `out` is a predefined variable in a jsp. Otherr are `response`, `request`, `session`,...

Comment: That is giving this output:  `[I@8ba95be`

Comment: Àlso I'm trying to retrieve the fibSequence I passed over not create a new array. How can I pull the value from the redirect?

Comment: Seems to be printing the memory address not the integer values.

Comment: Ok, will post as little workaround for passing an array as URL parameter. See EDIT2 in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks, will this work for my the decoding part of the solution work on a jsp page? I pasted it in but it gets recognized as text..maybe if I put these tags `<%` around the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better answer to transfer array variable from servlet to jsp page:

```
In Servelet:
String arr[] = {"array1","array2"};
request.setAttribute("arr",arr);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourpage.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

```
In Jsp:
<% String str[] = (String[]) request.getAttribute("arr"); %>
<%= str[0]+""+str[1] %>
```