# How to make Collection or Array to hold values from double type variable

Tags: java, double

**EDIT:-**

How can I enable any Collection or Array to hold values from rowValue which is of double type so that values can be displayed on the browser.

```
public  double[] FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen() {
double rowValue;       
 double []arr=new double[22];
     int i=0;
     try
        {  
       con = getConnection();
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          String sql="some query";
       stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       rs = stmt.getResultSet();
     
       while(rs.next()) 
        {
           for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
             {
               vals[i]  = rs.getDouble(2);
             }
            i++;
         }
        }
     catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("\nException "+e);
        }
   
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double v : vals) max = Math.max(max, v);
    int bucketCount = 1 + (int)(max/10);
    double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bucketCount; i1++){
      
        buckets[i1][0] = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //  iterate the rows
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < vals.length; i1++)
    {
        double v = vals[i1];
       double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v);
       double delta = Math.abs(mult - v);
       int bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d);
       if (buckets[bIdx][0] > delta)
        {
          buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;
            buckets[bIdx][1] = i1;
            buckets[bIdx][2] = v;
        }
    }

    for (int i1 =1; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)
    {
        double[] bucket = buckets[i1];
        rowValue = bucket[2];
        System.out.println(rowValue);
    }
   return rowValue ;
}
```

I want to convert rowValue into an array ,so that I can display its values in browser. Currently only last value of rowValue is being displayed as I have taken it as a double type variable.
I tried in this way

```
 for (int i1 =1; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)
    {
        bucket = buckets[i1];
      
        System.out.println(bucket);
        
    }
return bucket;
```

But when I run this code then in-spite of bucket values,I get values of @ form.How to resolve it?

> [D@1108727
>
> [D@191e4c
>
> [D@11415c8
>
> [D@1a220e6 -----

Comment: `Arrays.toString(double [] arr)`. That or, just write a nested loop if you need to display it in certain format..

Comment: You get the one-dimensional array reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : how to convert int array to String with toString method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/java-how-to-convert-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method)

Comment: @immibis ,here I'm trying to convert double into array  and there its convert array into string .Both are different I think.

Comment: @MES "How do I convert a double into an array" doesn't even make sense... It's like asking "How do I convert a parking space into a carpark?" I'm sure you're trying to do something sensible, but I don't know what it is (and neither do other people, judging by the responses)

Comment: My actual problem is sum thing else.I wanted to print the rowValues into browser in a tabular format and for that I need a collection or array  which can hold all the values of rowValue.But I'm not getting the actual way to do that.

Comment: @ajb sometimes someone posts a comment that's so irrelevant I wish I could downvote it. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays don't override `toString()`, so you're getting the default `toString()` from `Object`. You could use [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29) like

```
// System.out.println(bucket);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bucket));
```

You might also print all of the buckets at once with [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(buckets));
```

Comment: yes now values are shown but it is not what I wanted ,the values displayed is                                                                                                     **[0.020000457763671875, 8.0, 20.020000457763672]**                        and what I wanted is 
**20.02**,
**30.01**,
**39.99**,                                                                                                         The loop which I applied for buckets is wrong I think.