# Printing an array in Java method

Tags: java

So I need to print an array of integers into a String, and I have it almost right with one problem

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] anArray) {
    String x = "";
    String y = "";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        y = Integer.toString(anArray[i]);
        x = x + ", " + y;
    }
    result = "[" + x + "]";
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayInt[] = new int[] { 80, 100, 80, 92, 95, 87, 82, 76, 45, 76, 80, 70};
    System.out.println("array : " + arrayToString(arrayInt));
}
```

When I execute the code, instead of printing:

> [80, 100, 80, 92, 95, 87, 82, 76, 45, 76, 80, 70]

I get:

> [, 80, 100, 80, 92, 95, 87, 82, 76, 45, 76, 80, 70]

This should be really simple to me but I'm stuck, where do I need to put an exception to remove it?

Comment: Arrays.toString? Or only append the , for i>0.

Comment: Describe your printing logic with words. What happens to the first element?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(arrayInt);` What's a problem?

Comment: Also don't concatenate strings in loop. Use `StrinbBuilder` instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/4645155/1393766

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: What is the value of `x` in your first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding an extra `,` in the beginning. One simple way to get rid of it is,
Replace

```
result = "[" + x + "]";
```

with

```
result = "[" + x.substring(1) + "]";
```

---

But the best solution would be to use `Arrays.toString`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting an *extra comma* `,` at the beginning. This will solve your problem in the `arrayToString` function:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] anArray) {
    String x = "";
    String y = "";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length-1; i++) {
        y = Integer.toString(anArray[i]);
        x = x + y + ",";
    }
    y = Integer.toString(anArray[anArray.length-1]);
    x = x + y;
    result = "[" + x + "]";
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String arrayToString(int[] anArray) {
    String x = "";
    String y = "";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        y = Integer.toString(anArray[i]);
        if(x.isEmpty()){
            x = y;
        } else {
            x = x + ", " + y;
        }
    }
    result = "[" + x + "]";
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayInt[] = new int[] { 80, 100, 80, 92, 95, 87, 82, 76, 45, 76, 80, 70 };
    System.out.println("array : " + arrayToString(arrayInt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include check for first element.

`if( i == 0 )
     x = y;
 else
     x = x + ", " + y;`

Answer (score -1):

**Please change the last line in your code, result string variable as below:**

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] anArray) {
String x = "";
String y = "";
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    y = Integer.toString(anArray[i]);
    x = x + ", " + y;
}
 result = "[" + x + "]";
 return result.charAt(0)+result.substring(3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to use a java method but wasn't sure how to execute them