# Converting an integer array to a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am a beginner trying writing a program for a Caesar cipher assignment for class. Currently I am stuck trying to create a function that will do the opposite of the first function, take in an integer array and return a String. I'm completely lost on how to do so at this point and could really really use some help.

```
public static int[] string(String str) {
    int [] arr = new int [str.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {   
        str.toUpperCase();
        arr[i] = str.charAt(i)-65;
        // System.out.println(arr[i]);--> check to see if stringTo was working
    }
    return arr;
}



public static String symbol(int[] symbols) { 
    String message = new String();

    char[] letters = new char[symbols.length];



    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {

        symbols[i] = letters[i];

        message.toUpperCase();
        message =  message.toString();


        System.out.print(message);

    }    

    return message; 
}
```

Comment: String class has constructor `new String(char[] value)`. Just use it.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/how-to-convert-an-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

String str = "";

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    str = str + Integer.toString(a[i]);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Quick follow up question: What if I need to change the int arr to chars before it becomes a string. I think that was what I was having the most trouble with.

Comment: You don't need `Integer.toString()`. `str=str+arr[i]` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Approach using Java 8 Streams:

```
 int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

 String result = IntStream.of(intArray)
                          .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
 System.out.println(result); // "1,2,3,4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code in your first function correctly then you want something that converts `[1,2,3,4,5]` into `"12345"` right?

Then your function could look like this:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] array) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i : array) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this can have terrible performance for long arrays since each `+=` creates a new `String` so actually this would be better:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] array) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i : array) {
        builder.append(i);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

*javac* or the *JVM* might actually convert the first code snippet into the second one automcatically.

Comment: Yes, the compiler might. This is an easy append that I think java 5 or 7.. don't remember which will probably try to convert it into one String and it'll have the same impact as using a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code to help you.

```
public String changeIntToString(int aNumber){
    String theString = "";
    theString += aNumber;
    return theString;
}
```

Anything added to a String will turn into a String. So here's another example.

```
String lotOfInt = "" + 1 + 2 + 3;
```

That will get turn into a string of "123". I think you get the picture. Now you just need to loop through that array and combine it into a string.

Bonus and right way to do it... Use StringBuilder class. Search what it is and how to use it. ;)

Edited: Ah. MartinS beat me to it. :)