# i have question i got error like this [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@26f0a63f]

Tags: java

i have source code like this

```
public class Solution {

     private static List<Integer[]> twoSum(int[] numbers, int targets) {
         Map<Integer, Integer> arrayMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<Integer[]> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (arrayMap.containsKey(targets - numbers[i])) {
                    Integer[] temp = { arrayMap.get(targets - numbers[i]), i }; // Put the previous and current index
                    pairList.add(temp);
                }
                else arrayMap.put(numbers[i], i);
            }
            return pairList;
        }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int[]nums = {2, 7, 2, 11, 15}; 
            int target=9;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
            List<Integer[]> index =twoSum(nums, target);
            System.out.println(index.toString());
            
        }
}
```

but i want to run i got error like this

```
[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@26f0a63f]
```

how to fix my problem ?

Comment: That's not an error message. That's just what an array (in a list) looks like when you print it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t an error message. It’s the result of calling `toString` on an instance of type `List<Integer[]>`.

Simply put, array types in Java don’t define a useful `toString` method. Instead of the array contents, they print the type of the array and its address in memory, hence the `"[Ljava.lang.Integer;@26f0a63f"`. To print an array’s contents, [you need to invoke the static helper method `Arrays.toString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904956/1968) instead. And in your case you will need to do this manually for every item in your `List<Integer[]>`:

```java
System.out.println("[");
for (final Integer[] nested : index) {
    System.out.printf("  %s,\n", Arrays.toString(nested));
}
System.out.println("]");
```

An arguably better way of writing this, because it uses the `List.toString` method, is using the stream API:

```java
final List<String> indexStr = index.stream()
    .map(Arrays::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(indexStr);
```

(Note that I’m not calling `indexStr.toString()` explicitly — passing an object to `println` does that automatically for me!)